# How to use biblatex chapter+?

Tags: biblatex, biber

If you allow me, I'll start with with a (not so) minimum example from [biblatex: segmented bibliography with name of chapter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/155748/) which uses `refsegment=chapter` of [biblatex](https://mirror-hk.koddos.net/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) and will do the slight change of adding the  plus sign to the  option `refsegment=chapter+`.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@chapapp}{Segment}
\makeatother

\usepackage{nameref}  

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    %bibencoding=utf8,
    % refsection=chapter,
    refsegment=chapter+,
    url=false,
    sorting=none,
    sortcites=true,
    sorting=nyt,
    style=apa
    %style=numeric
]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

\makeatletter
%\newcommand*{\currentname}{\@currentlabelname}
\makeatother


% segmented bibliography
\defbibheading{subbibliography}{\subsection*{References for  Segment~\ref{refsegment:\therefsection\therefsegment}: \nameref{refsegment:\therefsection\therefsegment} }}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  references = {Works Cited},
}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=false,
}


\begin{document}

\author{John Doe}
\title{Bla bla}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First, there was light}
% \label{chapter1}

\lipsum[0-1]
Cite an author not previously cited~\cite{cicero}.
Note: Alphabetcially, K comes before S.

\section{A Section}

\lipsum[0-1]
Cite an author not previously cited~\cite{cicero}.
Note: Alphabetcially, K comes before S.

\chapter{Then, there was a power outage}
% \label{chapter2}

\lipsum[0-1]
And then again cite some authoprs cited previously~\cite{kastenholz}.
At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum~\cite{sigfridsson}.

\printbibheading
% \bibbysection[heading=subbibliography]
\bibbysegment[heading=subbibliography]

\end{document}
```

Doing so I get the error:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.cfg)

! Package biblatex Error: Option 'refsegment=chapter+' invalid.

See the biblatex package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.13809 \blx@processoptions

?
```

Why is that?

The `chapter+` option is there on page 52 of biblatex document.

Comment: `chapter+` was added in version 3.12 of `biblatex` following https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/773 and https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pull/809. Do you use that version or an older version of `biblatex`? You can add `\listfiles` to the beginning of your document to get the version of `biblatex` you use printed in a nice little table at the end of the `.log` file.

Comment: BTW If you *need* `\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}` for the document to compile, your `biblatex` is definitely much too old. That line is not needed in newer versions of `biblatex` and `biblatex-apa` (`biblatex` >= 3.8, `biblatex-apa` >= 7.5 from November 2017)

Comment: Looks like you got it, I have `biblatex.sty    2018/03/04 v3.11` and thanks for mentioning `\listfile`. Updating to MacTeX 2019 now )

Comment: `sorting=none, sortcites=true, sorting=nyt, style=apa` looks a bit indecisive. If you want to use APA style, `style=apa` alone should be enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/773 and https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pull/809 extended values like `chapter+` for the 'sectioning-valued' options were introduced in `biblatex` v3.12. If you are using an older version you should look into updating your system.

---

Note that in newer versions of `biblarex` and `biblatex-apa` you won't need `\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}` any more. Starting from `biblatex-apa` 7.5 and `biblatex` 3.8 (November 2017) the language mappings are applied automatically.

For proper APA style you want to replace `sorting=none, sortcites=true, sorting=nyt, style=apa,`

with the simple

```
style=apa,
```