# Segmented bibliography with name of section

Tags: biblatex, biber

A related issue can be found at [biblatex: segmented bibliography with name of chapter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/155748/).

If you allow me, I'll start with with a (not so) minimum example from [How to use biblatex chapter+?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/488541/how-to-use-biblatex-chapter?noredirect=1#comment1233606_488541) which uses refsegment=chapter+ of biblatex and slight change it 
to `refsegment=subsection+` and adding `\section{A Section}`:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@chapapp}{Segment}
\makeatother

\usepackage{nameref}  

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    %bibencoding=utf8,
    % refsection=chapter,
    refsegment=subsection+,
    url=false,
    sorting=none,
    sortcites=true,
    sorting=nyt,
    style=apa
    %style=numeric
]{biblatex}
% \DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

\makeatletter
%\newcommand*{\currentname}{\@currentlabelname}
\makeatother


% segmented bibliography
\defbibheading{subbibliography}{\subsection*{References for  Segment~\ref{refsegment:\therefsection\therefsegment}: \nameref{refsegment:\therefsection\therefsegment} }}

% \DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
%   references = {Works Cited},
% }

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=false,
}


\begin{document}

\author{John Doe}
\title{Bla bla}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First, there was light}
% \label{chapter1}

\lipsum[0-1]
Cite an author not previously cited~\cite{cicero}.
Note: Alphabetcially, K comes before S.

\section{A Section}

\lipsum[0-1]
Cite an author not previously cited~\cite{cicero}.
Note: Alphabetcially, K comes before S.

\chapter{Then, there was a power outage}
% \label{chapter2}

\lipsum[0-1]
And then again cite some authoprs cited previously~\cite{kastenholz}.
At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum~\cite{sigfridsson}.

\printbibheading
% \bibbysection[heading=subbibliography]
\bibbysegment[heading=subbibliography]

\end{document}
```

So I get:

[image]

Altough, what I want it this:

[image]

See the section name? To get I did:

```
\section{A Section}
\newrefsegment
```

Shouldn't that be happening automatic due to `refsegment=subsection+`? Or is it necessary to add `\newrefsegment`?

As a alternative approach I found helpfull to:

```
\newcommand*{\segtion}[1]{\section{#1}\newrefsegment}
```

Another alternative might be to redefine it but I was not sucessfull on my try:

```
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{\section{#1}\newrefsegment}
```

Comment: I'd have to look into this in more detail, but at the moment I'd say that the problem is a timing issue. When you use `refsegment=subsection+` `biblatex` patches the sectioning commands to automatically call `\newrefsegment`. `\newrefsegment` then sets the `\label` you later `\ref` in your heading definition. If we want the references to match properly, we need the `\label` and thus `\newrefsegment` to be executed after the sectioning command has increased the counter. At the moment it looks like that is the case for `\chapter` but not for `\section`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `biblatex` 3.13 has a fix for this issue with `memoir` and the KOMA-Script classes.
>   A structurally similar issue is still present for the standard classes: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/914
>
> Update your TeX distribution to obtain the current versions of `biblatex` and Biber if you are using `memoir` or one of the KOMA-Script classes.
>
> The workarounds presented below are not needed any more.

This might be considered a bug in `biblatex`, but at the very least it is very unfortunate behaviour. https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pull/887 contains a fix for the issue in `memoir`: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pull/887/commits/9a617ad88d6dd6cf84cad6d9e2b5216622b668ed.

The core of the problem is a timing issue with a patch `biblatex` applies. When you say `refsection=section` `biblatex` goes about patching internals of the command `\section` so that every time you execute `\section` the command also calls `\newrefsegment`. The exact timing of `\newrefsegment` call within the internals of `\section` plays an important role here.

You exploit that `\newrefsegment` automatically defines a label `\label{refsegment:\the\c@refsection\the\c@refsegment}%`. `\label`s usually attach to the last counter that was increased with `\refstepcounter`. Obviously you want the label to attach to the sectioning command that just triggered `\newrefsegment`. That means that `\newrefsegment` must be called *after* the internals of the `\section` command have issued `\refstepcounter{section}`. On the other hand, we usually want to execute `\newrefsegment` as early as possible to make sure that the contents of the section heading are already in the new segment (it would be confusing if a citation in the heading would be counted as part of the previous refsegment).

For `\section` and friends `biblatex` up to version 3.12 would just add `\newrefsegment` to the beginning of the internal command `\@startsection` (or their `memoir`/KOMA-Script equivalent). That is early enough to already apply to the heading text, but in fact too early to pick up the correct `\refstepcounter` for the label. That explains why the label for the `\section` just repeats the value for the previous `\chapter`. (`\chapter`, incidentally, seems to be patched early enough already...)

Fortunately, both the KOMA-Script author (recently) and the `memoir` author (quite a while ago) started to offer 'hook' mechanisms that can be used to execute `\newrefsegment` and friends in the right spot within `\section`. The use of those hooks is implemented in https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pull/887 present in `biblatex` 3.13. There is no solution for the standard classes yet. At the moment it looks like one would have to resort to a more precise `\patchcmd` instead of the simple `\pretocmd`.

In case you are stuck with an old version of `biblatex` you can remove

```
refsegment=subsection+,
```

and do what it should do with

```
\apptocmd\memchapinfo{\newrefsegment}{}{}
\apptocmd\memchapstarinfo{\newrefsegment}{}{}

\makeatletter
\apptocmd\memsecinfo{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{section}
    {\@firstoftwo}
    {\ifstrequal{#1}{subsection}
       {\@firstoftwo}
       {\@secondoftwo}}
    {\newrefsegment}
    {}%
}{}{}
\apptocmd\memsecstarinfo{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{section}
    {\@firstoftwo}
    {\ifstrequal{#1}{subsection}
       {\@firstoftwo}
       {\@secondoftwo}}
    {\newrefsegment}
    {}%
}{}{}
\makeatother
```

That's a bit clunky, but better than nothing, I guess.

---

BTW

```
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{\section{#1}\newrefsegment}
```

results in an infinite loop because LaTeX is a macro replacement language. With that definition you tell LaTeX to replace every occurrence of `\section{<argument>}` with `\section{<argument>}\newrefsegment`. You can easily see how that results in a loop when LaTeX tries to replace the `\section{<argument>}` again.

```
\newcommand*{\segtion}[1]{\section{#1}\newrefsegment}
```

On the contrary works, because the command name is different, which avoids the infinite loop.