# Display the type of citation, "Book", "Journal" etc. in bibtex output

Tags: bibtex

I'm using the `unsrt.bst` bib style and wish to modify it so that in the output it starts with what the type of entry was:

> [1] BOOK: A. N. Other etc...
>
> [2] ARTICLE: A. N. Other etc....

But I break the `.bst` file no matter there I put a "BOOK: " entry. Any ideas? I only use a small subset of the types of citation so could easily just amend the `.bst` case by case instead of a in a general way. If I knew how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `unsrt.bst` the following recipe works.

1. Locate `unsrt.bst` on your machine. You can do this by typing `kpsewhich unsrt.bst` into the command line/terminal. Alternatively, obtain a copy of the file from CTAN http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/base/unsrt.bst
2. Copy the file to a location where TeX can find it. The document directory will do fine. See also https://texfaq.org/FAQ-inst-wlcf
3. Rename the file to `unsrt-typed.bst`, say (the license of `unsrt.bst` requires you to change the name if you modify the file)
4. Find `FUNCTION {output.bibitem}` (ll. 85-93) and replace the complete function definition with

   ```
   FUNCTION {output.bibitem}
   { newline$
     "\bibitem{" write$
     cite$ write$
     "}" write$
     newline$
     type$ "u" change.case$ ":" * write$
     newline$
     ""
     before.all 'output.state :=
   }
   ```

   That is, add the two lines

   ```
     type$ "u" change.case$ ":" * write$
     newline$
   ```

   Note that the `"u" change.case$` gives us the ALL CAPS, if you wanted all-lower case you'd just say

   ```
     type$ ":" * write$
   ```

   If you wanted to apply a LaTeX macro, you'd say

   ```
     "\textbf{" type$ * "}:" * write$
   ```
5. Add a comment with your name, the current date and a short description of the changes to the top of the file.
6. Use `\bibliographystyle{unsrt-typed}` instead of `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}` in your document.

As alternative for steps 1 to 5 you can obtain the patched version of the file at https://gist.github.com/moewew/e0c609d7162524a9f82d74cff14bdc61

Then

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{sigfridsson,
  author  = {Sigfridsson, Emma and Ryde, Ulf},
  title   = {Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the
             electrostatic potential and moments},
  journal = {Journal of Computational Chemistry},
  year    = 1998,
  volume  = 19,
  number  = 4,
  pages   = {377-395},
  doi     = {10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P},
}
@book{nussbaum,
  author    = {Nussbaum, Martha},
  title     = {Aristotle's \enquote{De Motu Animalium}},
  year      = 1978,
  publisher = {Princeton University Press},
  address   = {Princeton},
}
@phdthesis{geer,
  author  = {de Geer, Ingrid},
  title   = {Earl, Saint, Bishop, Skald~-- and Music:
             The {Orkney Earldom} of the Twelfth Century.
             {A} Musicological Study},
  school  = {Uppsala Universitet},
  year    = 1985,
  address = {Uppsala},
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,nussbaum,geer}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt-typed}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image: Bibliography with entry type in ALL CAPS: e.g. "ARTICLE: Emma Sigfridsson and Ulf Ryde. Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments. Journal of Computational Chemistry, 19(4):377–395, 1998."]

---

A more naive approach would be adding

```
"<TYPE>: " write$
```

after `output.bibitem` in each type `FUNCTION`.

The article function would then read

```
FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
  "ARTICLE: " write$
  format.authors "author" output.check
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$
    { journal emphasize "journal" output.check
      format.vol.num.pages output
      format.date "year" output.check
    }
    { format.article.crossref output.nonnull
      format.pages output
    }
  if$
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}
```

But obviously that is more work. See https://gist.github.com/moewew/e7e53020544f16d3db619ca8b33f1896. On the plus side you are more flexible in the output since you don't have to rely on `type$`, which will only give you the formal BibTeX entry type. (`article` where one might want to say "Journal article" etc.)

---

Of course with `biblatex` those sort of things don't need manipulation of `.bst` files: [How to label bibliography items, books and articles and others?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/488564/35864)